# Please tell me the diffrence in nuance between the following two sentences

Tags: difference

Would you please tell me the difference in nuance between the following two sentences?

1. When the sun sets, I will still be running toward the goal.
2. When the sun sets, I will be still running toward the goal.

Comment: How about "When the sun sets, I will be running still toward the goal."? Anyway you are just moving the adverb around, not changing the meaning in your context.

Comment: #1 is how a native speaker would probably say it, that or (less likely) "... I still will be running toward the goal." #2 is how someone who was fumbling for words would likely say it.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is very subtle.  Basically, it's a matter on emphasizing "running" or emphasizing "still".  "I will still be running" emphasizes that you are *continuing* to run, while "I will be still running" emphasizes that you are running (continuously), and not doing something else.